Using LSTMs for Predicting Targets with Known Feature Vector
I am trying to use an LSTM to predict the consecutive "offset" calibration values for an instrument. These offset values have previously been shown to be well correlated with a pair of temperature values, which are used as the features. These offset values show a periodicity, so an LSTM was chosen for the model. However, all the examples of LSTMs I have found use the feature vectors from the previous sequence of data points to predict the target. I feel that this might not capture the relationship between each feature vector in the sequence and its offset. And because only the feature vectors of the prior sequence of data points are used in the prediction, the will not be able to use that temperature-offset relationship effectively.
To counter this, I have already added the present data point's feature vector to the sequences of vectors used to train the model and, naturally, the sequences used to predict the target offsets.
However, how might I be able to weight the feature vector for the offset to be predicted more heavily to allow the model to take advantage of the temperature-offset relationship?
The code to create the sequences looks like this:
def create_sequences(x, y, time_steps = 24):
    xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(x) - time_steps - 1):
        x_temp = x[i:(i + time_steps + 1)] #Creates a sequence of time_steps before the target value
        xs.append(x_temp)
        ys.append(y[i + time_steps]) #The target value is the value after the sequence
    return np.array(xs), np.array(ys)

Thank you! 
